# App Transport Security issue with AVAudioPlayer loading local file objective-C, XCode 9

Tags: objective-c, avaudioplayer, app-transport-security, xcode9.3, ios11.3

I have an app which loads a bundled m4a audio file as a local resource and it has worked well for many years now.  I'm updating the app to iOS 11.3/XCode 9.3 and it is now failing on iPad (works on iPhone) when I press my play button:

```
2018-05-13 20:45:24.437626-0700 my app[6175:218735] App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
2018-05-13 20:45:24.437791-0700 my app[6175:218735] Cannot start load of Task <117E064E-ABB3-45F2-8D64-76397B140092>.<0> since it does not conform to ATS policy
2018-05-13 20:45:24.437948-0700 my app[6175:218732] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1022
```

My code:

```
NSURL *medURL   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"MyFile"
                                          withExtension: @"m4a"];
NSError *playerError = nil;
AVAudioPlayer *newPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: medURL error: &playerError];
self.appSoundPlayer = newPlayer;

// "Preparing to play" attaches to the audio hardware and ensures that playback
//      starts quickly when the user taps Play
[appSoundPlayer prepareToPlay];
```

It fails on the `prepareToPlay`.

Reading other answers I've found a lot of information on the ATS error so I added this to my plist file for the app, cleaned, rebuilt and ran it -- but I am still getting the error:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
    <true/> </dict>
```

I can't use the NSExceptionDomain key because this is a local resource, there is no domain.  How can I fix this?

Note: to be clear, this file is bundled into the app and has not been downloaded at any time.  This is not an "http" url, it is a "file:" url.

Update: Looking at the [CFNetworkLog](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/app-transport-security/) I realized that there was a `NSURLConnection` to the network happening just before the audio prep in `AppDelegate`.  When I removed this call everything started working.  Since both work independently, it appears to me that there is some sort of conflict in `NSURLConnection` which is happening -- possibly a bug in the API?  It would be good to know what the proper work-around is for this, I have gotten it to work well enough by removing the `prepareToPlay` call above -- this is not ideal as it takes longer when the user goes to play the audio file.

Another update: the app started working today for no apparent reason, I hadn't changed anything since the last time I tried it.  Unfortunately I can't determine if fixes work at this point!  To be sure, it does appear that my plist keys are working in my iOS 11.3 simulator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170975/discussion-between-abhishek-thapliyal-and-alan-moore).

Comment: You added a bounty, but you haven't provided the details the chat.  Please try the things in the chat.  ATS should not be blocking anything that is referenced in the local file system.  I think something else is going on here. Specifically turning on the CFNetwork Logging so you can see the URL it is trying to load.  There might be another problem going on with how the prepareToPlay method works.

Comment: Re: "I can't use the NSExceptionDomain key because this is a local resource, there is no domain. How can I fix this?" *Actually there is a domain*, "localhost", maybe try using that. [Here's a quick example](https://gist.github.com/ParityError/ca6b16a04b8c44a580ab6c39527f567e). And yes, without PrepareToPlay users with older devices might experience so much lag they'd rather Quit than Play...

Comment: Also, by using `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent`, `NSAllowsLocalNetworking`, `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia` you are overriding `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`. I recommend reading ["App Transport Security dictionary primary keys"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW34) thoroughly to understand what keys should be included. Including conflicting keys is pointless; you'll just end up with the same undesired behavior.

Comment: did you try use `pathForResource:ofType:`

Comment: This is a legacy app, I want it to continue working on older iOS versions.      When I removed the other NSURLConnection, I found that my NSAllows* keys were working correctly so I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: The url appears to be: file:///Users/alyanm/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8F2A97B1-72E8-4951-B694-52197EDA1AE3/data/Containers/Data/Application/12C2C580-A2B0-4B14-A1D0-81A0BAD3B3EB/Library/Cookies/com.mydomain.med.myappname.binarycookies  -- but CFNetworkLogging doesn't report the error?  Strangely, it has started working just now.  Might be a race condition which I may have trouble reproducing!

Answer (score 6):

In my project is using AVAudioPlayer to play audio, and my source code:

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyFile"  ofType:@"m4a"];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
AVAudioPlayer* audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1; //Infinite
[audioPlayer setVolume:1];
[audioPlayer play];
```